# Should I remove the drywall before building new walls against existing walls?

Tags: walls, framing

[image: Pantry Wall]

I'm closing off a walk through to the kitchen from hallway creating a pantry in its place. Is this overkill to open up wall to access studs for secure mounting of new framing? I'm building custom shelves in pantry that will carry significant weight.

I use to do HVAC years ago and have always done this type of work when installing duct work through small closets in hallways or bedrooms. We would open up the walls and frame to the existing studs instead of applying framing to the drywall or plaster.

I'm being told by two "handymen" general contractors that I should have just nailed 2x4s to plaster for the drywall. I still have to frame out the front and add a door. Is there another approved way of framing out the front of the pantry without opening up walls that I'm not aware of?

(This is a load bearing wall in picture.)

Comment: it is unclear what the " new framing " is for.  Are you just adding a door and need to create the proper sized RO (rough opening) or are you closing the wall in the photo completely or partially?   The phrase "should have just nailed 2x4s to plaster for the drywall"  is very confusing. Can you give us a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: The opening is going to be closed completely. It originally was a walk through from the hallway to the kitchen. The picture is of the hallway side. Once this opening is closed it will support custom shelves inside the pantry. when Referring to the 2x4. it was told to me that instead of accessing the studs by removing some of the plaster that I should have nailed 2x4's to the exsisting opening and used the 2x4's for the new drywall to screw too.

Comment: Closing as unclear at the request of the OP. Feel free to clarify the question and request to have it reopened.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it your way (the right way).   You will never have to worry in the future, in comparison with the other approach.

Have you asked the 2 contractors "what they would do if this was their home"....maybe their answer would differ.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would have never questioned it but having two people give opposite of what I would have expected made me stop. I'm not a carpenter by trade so I rather be humble and ask for correction than do something wrong. Obviously what I was doing wasn't wrong just caused me to pause and reevaluate if what i was doing was overkill. Thanks again.

Comment: just for disclaimer : I am no pro, just common sense speaking.  I, however, just did a 4 month "construction company management" course, and from what I learnt about carpentry (90 hour course), I would open up the wall entirely (as per your method) just to ensure this doesn't bite back at you in the future.       Good luck on the project :)

Comment: I am not sure I understand the  exact nature of what you want to do, but if you are just adding shelves on a wall, you can find the studs with a stud finder and determine whether the number and dimensions of the studs would support the shelves through the drywall. People add cabinets without removing drywall. How much weight are you going to place on these shelves?

Answer (score 1):

I would find the studs in the wall with a stud finder and then mount my 2 x 4's to the studs through the drywall - since you are going to put significant weight on the shelves that would be my approach. As for the front - I am not seeing the issue perhaps I am not following you. The picture shows the access area with the framing removed is that where the door is going to go ? I do not see any reason you need to remove the dry wall to frame out the front and the door .. perhaps you might want to post a drawing of what you have and what you intend to do  ?

Comment: Mount the 2x4s horizontally  with attention to having some at heights appropriate for cabinet mounting

Answer (score 0):

I've done many remodeling projects of this type, and have never found it necessary to remove the drywall just for purposes of framing.. You can certainly frame against drywall as long as the studs are fastened securely at the top and bottom.

If you like, use construction glue to mount the studs to the drywall in the middle of the height if you don't have solid backing behind. The combination of that and the stiffness of the studs is more than adequate. Double the studs against the drywall if you want extra peace of mind. This will add enough stiffness that even the weight on your shells won't move it substantially.

That said, you have plenty of drywall work to do anyway. If it makes you feel more comfortable to open things up, go ahead and do it.